# C++ How do I erase a line from the console?

Tags: c++, windows-console

So I have this code that I'm working on and I used a switch statement. What I want to do is when any invalid option is selected, the program should display a message and then after some time clear only the message while keeping the options still on screen.
In my so far of a code, I used Windows.h library's Sleep function for a pause and also used goto to go back to asking the option but can't seem to figure out how to erase the error message from the screen. I can't use `system("cls");` because I have a menu before this option selection kind of like a login so I don't want it gone until a valid option has been selected.
Here's my code:

```
cout<<endl<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t                            - Access Denied! -"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t                         + Press [1] To Try Again. +"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t                         + Press [2] To Go Back. +"<<endl;
char TryAgain = ' ';
cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t                                 >>[ ]<< ";
InvalidOption:
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdout, { 84, 14 });
cin>>TryAgain;
switch (TryAgain)
{
    case '1':
        goto LoginAgain;
    case '2':
        break;
    default:
        {
            cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t                            Select A Valid Option!";
            Sleep ( 450 );
            cout << "\b";
            goto InvalidOption;
        }
}
```

Yes I'm using tons of `/t` and maybe a bunch of other stuff but its just a sample code I was trying instead of directly experimenting on my original project.

Comment: Unfortunately, standard C++ just writes to `stdout`, which can be a file, or anything else. There is no support for colors, positions, clearing, etc. You need to use a library to add that support. `SetConsoleCursorPosition` implies that you already have such a library. What library is that that you're using?

Comment: Did you try to move the cursor where the message is and output spaces( ' ' ) to erase?

Comment: Side note: `goto` is hard to get right, and if you pull it off you'll find it's even harder to prove to others that you got it right. In the long run you are almost always better off using functions and conventional loops.

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm using the Windows.h libray for that.

Comment: Wouldn't it kind of flood the screen with spaces I mean isn't it a bad move? I'm trying to avoid as many beginner mistakes as possible. @Alex

Comment: @user4581301 yes but well I'm pretty trained with goto now and I very often use a mix of goto and loops. I find it fun and easy for myself lol.

Comment: That's your call, but if you go pro you'll encounter a little thing called Code Review. It's next to impossible to get a `goto` statement through a Code Review.

Comment: @Umair, the cleanest way is to redraw. So you have a scene. You can make functions - showMainMenu( int x, int y), showMainMenu( int x, int y, int subMenu ), showError( int x, int y, int errCode ), etc. and then use cls() and call the functions to redraw. You can even create layers later :) that is the way, a scene is drawn on the screen. And I don`t think drawing spaces does some problem. Create a function ConsoleGoTo( int x, int y ) and wrap SetConsoleCursorPosition() to be more clean and handy.

Comment: [Windows Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN) looks like the right tool. I hope some people who have experience with it would add some answers.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for the information, next time i'll try to use loops more than goto!

Comment: I have some functions like that to show menus and etc but yes thank you for the idea of the error scene!

Comment: You want something along the lines of the `ncurses` library.

Answer (score 6):

If your terminal supports it, you can use ANSI escape codes ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Terminal_output_sequences), [here](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm)), which provide more advanced console text control that allows you to remove multiple lines, print colored text, and skip all over the place.

The general format is `ESC[X` where `ESC` is the ASCII escape char (`0x1b`), and `X` is the command. Many times `X` will be preceded by an integer argument, like in `ESC[1A` below, where `1` is the number of lines to move up.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

// Erases `count` lines, including the current line
void eraseLines(int count) {
    if (count > 0) {
        std::cout << "\x1b[2K"; // Delete current line
        // i=1 because we included the first line
        for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
            std::cout
            << "\x1b[1A" // Move cursor up one
            << "\x1b[2K"; // Delete the entire line
        }
        std::cout << "\r"; // Resume the cursor at beginning of line
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t         text" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t         more text" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t      even   more text \t\t" << std::endl;
    eraseLines(4);
    std::cout << "No one's here..." << std::endl;
}
```

*Works on [replit](https://repl.it/@KeinR/ANSI-escape-codes-example) and with Cygwin Mintty*

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the carriage-return character `\r`. It usually goes together with line-feed `\n`, but its standalone function is "return the printing position to beginning of line". On some terminals, if you print that, you can print a bunch of spaces and overwrite your message.

```
cout << "\t\t\t\t\t Your stuff" << flush; // flush may be needed when you don't output \n
Sleep(450);
cout << "\r                          \r"; // return to start of line, print spaces, return again
```

All that provided you don't output a line-feed anywhere. If you do that, all is lost, you have to clear the whole screen.